# Не работает Js-код

Tags: javascript

Пробовал много чего, js плохо знаю

```js
// Загрузка другого HTML файла
fetch("other.html")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      contentElement.innerHTML = data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Ошибка:', error);
    });
```

Comment: а как вы определили, что он не работает?